# Riemannian metric being locally diagonalizable

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $(X,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold. I was thinking about the Poincare half plane, which has constant sectional curvature $-1$ and has metric $g=\begin{bmatrix}1/y^2 & 0\\0 & 1/y^2\end{bmatrix}$.

This isn't a topic I know much about, but I thought I remembered hearing somewhere that if a Riemannian metric is locally diagonalizable, it is flat (Riemann curvature is zero), but this would seem to contradict this example, since sectional curvature and Riemann curvature contain the same information. I think this has something to do with the fact that on a symplectic manifold, one can find Darboux coordinates, and so there is no notion of curvature for a symplectic manifold.

Also, I seem to remember hearing that all two dimensional Riemannian manifolds are conformally flat, which might have something to do with this. Anyway, I realized there are at least three loosely associated thoughts here, but I'd appreciate it if anyone could make some sense out of them.

Comment: To make the Riemann curvature zero, there would need to be a coordinate transformation that makes the components of $g$ independent of the coordinates.

Comment: Conformally flat means that there are isothermal (conformal) coordinates, in which the metric tensor is a multiple of the identity. Gauss showed (kind of) that every surface is conformally flat, but this is certainly false in dimension 3 and above. Also, conformally flat is a different notion than flat in the sense of curvature, which means that there are coordinates in which the metric tensor is constant.

Comment: @LukasGeyer conformally flat is probably what I was thinking then. Although I understand what you're saying about the metric having being constant with respect to the coordinates for the curvature to be zero, I'm a little confused on this point: So in the Poincare half plane, if you just scaled each tangent vector by $y$, you would get a global chart in which  $g$ with respect to this new basis is the identity. Wouldn't this mean that $(X,g)$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @user124910: The point is that there is no chart which realizes this transformation (scaling every tangent vector by $y$.)

Comment: @LukasGeyer Ah I see. Thank you for bearing with me and for your insights, Lukas!